How do i fix Instagram reel upload error - media upload has failed with error code 2207026
i wish to find a solution to this issue i have been facing for a long while, trying to publish a reel on instagram. It keeps returning this error: Media upload has failed with error code 2207026 which means its not in the required format, i have tried with countless videos, uploaded them to my google drive and input the link to the video but still the same error, i came across this: Facebook Graph API - Getting error 2207026 when trying to upload video
And also implemented the last suggesstion in my code as shown below:
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        String extension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
        var key = UUID.randomUUID() + "." + extension;
        String directory = this.fileStorageLocation;
        Path newPath = Paths.get(directory).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(newPath);
            Path inputFilePath = newPath.resolve(StringUtils.cleanPath(key));
            Path outputFilePath = newPath.resolve("output.mp4");
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), inputFilePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            executeFFmpegCommand(inputFilePath.toString(), outputFilePath.toString());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return key;
    }

    private void executeFFmpegCommand(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) throws IOException {
        String ffmpegPath = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe";
        String[] ffmpegCommand = {
                ffmpegPath,
                "-i", inputFilePath,
                "-c:v", "libx264",
                "-aspect", "16:9",
                "-crf", "18",
                "-vf", "scale=iw*min(1280/iw\\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(1280-iw)/2:(720-ih)/2",
                "-fpsmax", "60",
                "-preset", "ultrafast",
                "-c:a", "aac",
                "-b:a", "128k",
                "-ac", "1",
                "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
                "-movflags", "+faststart",
                "-t", "59",
                "-y", outputFilePath
        };

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand);
        processBuilder.inheritIO();
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        try {
            process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("FFmpeg command executed successfully.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException("Error executing FFmpeg command: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

And uploaded the video to my drive and put in the link again, but still the same error, i dont know could be the issue, could someone provide a suggestion or a link to a video that has been tested with, because i dont see what am doing wrong, thanks.

Did you fix your problem? Encountering the same

@ProjectX still couldnt fix it till now :(

process.waitFor(); returns a status code which may indicate that ffmpeg may have failed, and it may have written error messages to stderr log which you have not read / mentioned. If checking both of those does not help, you should debug with running FFmpeg standalone and submit the generated file

@DuncG Thanks for your response, but it did generate an mp4 file which i used, i have also used this for publishing to facebook and it works well, just instagram keeps showing this error and there is no way to upload the file directly instead of using a link google drive link.

@DavidOgbodu I got it to work, there was no problem on the API side, i had an error on my public link to my reel. I can share you my upload code if you want to

@ProjectX wowww!!! thats hope... yeah please share to my mail, or send the link to github to my mail: davidogbodu3056@gmail.com, and also the video you used as well... thanks
